# Huge difference between htop and ps aux output

Tags: ubuntu-14.04, cpu-usage, ps, htop

I am running a test on Ubuntu 14.04. When I check my CPU usage using 
'ps aux|grep service' then CPU usage is 0.1 of a process, while in htop for the same process the CPU% is 12.3.

Can anyone tell me the reason? or which value should I consider the right one?

Thanks

Answer (score 6, accepted):

They are measuring different things.

From the `ps` man-page:

```
   CPU usage is currently expressed as the percentage of time spent
   running during the entire lifetime of a process.  This is not ideal, 
   and it does not conform to the standards that ps otherwise conforms to.
   CPU usage is unlikely to add up to exactly 100%.
```

From the `htop` man-page (I am the author of `htop`):

```
   PERCENT_CPU (CPU%)
        The  percentage  of  the  CPU  time  that the process is currently
        using.
```

So, in `htop` this is the percentage of total CPU time used by the program between the last refresh of the screen and now.

*PercentageInHtop* = (non-idle CPU time used by process during the last 1.5s) / 1.5s

In `ps` this is the percentage of CPU time used by the program relative to the total time it exists (ie, since it was launched).

*PercentageInPs* = (non-idle CPU time used by process since process startup) / (time elapsed since process startup)

That is, in your reading it means that `htop` is saying that the service is taking 12.3% of your CPU *now*, while `ps` is saying that your service has spent 99.9% of its total life idle.

Comment: I didn't get it. I collected above reading at the same time. If ps is showing me the cpu% usage of the process since the process started, it should be approximately equal or logically greater than the htop, as htop is showing the reading since I wrote htop in my terminal right?

Comment: No. htop this is the percentage of total CPU time used by the program between the last *refresh of the screen* (the last time it recalculated values) and now (in other words, during the last 1.5 second, by default).

Comment: Shouldn't it be less than ps??

Comment: No, they are really totally different things! The usage in htop may be high because of a temporary spike, and in total the lifetime use of the process (reflected by ps) may still be low.

I added equations in the answer above to explain it more clearly.